# Regex to search for only carriage return and newline character in string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am Newbie to regex and need help to figure out how to form a regex to return False if Section One is empty and has no alphanumeric characters. Currently I am using the following regex, but it still considers newline, carriage return characters as strings.

Any help would be appreciated

```
PATTERN = r'Section One:[\s]*'
```

Input:

```
1. Section One:

2. Section Two: lknlknvd lknlfnv
lvkndflvlkvndflvkn
vlkfdnlkfn

3. Section Three:pklnklnfvl lknlknvl
flvkndflknvlf
```

Comment: are you passing the line or the buffer? what is your code / data more accurately. It may be a case for using `re.DOTALL` or `re.MULTILINE`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre If trying to match any amount of (empty) whitespace, then `\s*` should cover it.

Comment: Good question Jean, I am passing it as buffer. Does the results vary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use the following pattern:

```
Section One:\s*(?:\d+\.\s+Section|$)
```

This will be a positive match when the text `Section One:` is followed by nothing but whitespace before either another section header begins *or* the end of the string is hit.  I left open the possibility that maybe some of your inputs would only have a single empty section one.

```
import re

line = "1.Section One:\n\nSection Two: lknlknvd lknlfnv\nlvkndflvlkvndflvkn\nvlkfdnlkfn\n\n3. Section Three:pklnklnfvl lknlknvl\nflvkndflknvlf "

obj = re.match( r'.*Section One:\s+(?:\d+\.\s+Section|$)', line, re.M|re.I)

if obj:
    print "Section One has no content"
else:
    print "Section One has content"
```

### Demo

Comment: This works if the value is passed as string. But I am getting the value from a buffer output, which still honors \r\n characters as newline. Apologies for not mentioning this, but I also have a index number in front of each sections. I have edited the question now.

Comment: Tim, one last question. I have another regex to process a text r’Section One: [\t\f ]*[\w+]’ which pretty much considers text if it’s in the same line, but ignores text if it starts from the next line. I tried adding \s+ after your recent post but that didn’t seem to work. Can you please throw some light on how can the regex be tuned for such condition

Comment: @user16210528 You should open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You may want this one
`Section One:.*[a-z0-9].*$`

`re.MULTILINE` and `re.IGNORECASE` are used.

`.*[a-z0-9].*`: Match something contains at least one alphanumeric character, ie. `[a-z0-9]`. 
`$`: make sure matching against the whole line.

See https://regex101.com/r/H64ZCV/3 for example.